# how to put dynamic arraylist button in gridlayout or gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I am trying to display my dynamic button in grid layout.

**PROBLEM:**
I was using linear layout before but still i got some errors in getting a row and a column then i try to use gridlayout in my xml file but still the expectation is not right. I use adpater also for my columns and rows still i got some errors.

So I got a problem in displaying my code, it show only one button instead of the length of the string i want.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private String result="";
String sampleText = "The red fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
String[] words = sampleText.split("\\s");
private GridLayout ll;
Button button;
private final ArrayList<Button> buttonList = new ArrayList<>();
GridLayout.LayoutParams lp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final int noOfBtns  = words.length;
    ll =(GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.btnlay);
    final TextView tvtext = findViewById(R.id.result);
    final TextView text_quiz = findViewById(R.id.text_quiz);
    button = findViewById(R.id.validate);
    tvtext.setText(sampleText);
    final Button[] btns = new Button[noOfBtns];

    lp = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();

    for (int i = 0; i < noOfBtns; i++) {

    final int j = i;
    /*words[i] = words[i].replaceAll("[^\\w]", "");*/
    btns[i] = new Button(this);
    btns[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_button);
    btns[i].setWidth(0);
    btns[i].setText(words[i]);
    btns[i].setTag(i);
    btns[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            result = result + btns[j].getText().toString();
            if (j < noOfBtns) {

                text_quiz.append(words[j] + " ");
                btns[j].setEnabled(false);

            }
        }

    });
       /* buttonList.add(btns[i]);*/
    ll.removeAllViews();
    ll.setRowCount(10);
    ll.setColumnCount(7);
    Collections.shuffle(buttonList);
    ll.addView(btns[i],lp);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String answer = text_quiz.getText().toString().trim();
            if (sampleText.compareTo(answer) == 0) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Correct")
                        .setMessage("please click ok to continue until the end")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }).show();

            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                builder.setTitle("Incorrect");
                builder.setMessage("Your Answer is Incorrect.");
                builder.setCancelable(true);

                final AlertDialog dlg = builder.create();

                dlg.show();

                Handler mHandler = new Handler();
                Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        if (dlg != null && dlg.isShowing()) dlg.dismiss();
                    }
                };
                mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 2000);
                text_quiz.setText("");
                for (int a = 0; a < noOfBtns; a++) {
                    btns[a].setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my xml file:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.144">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/icon1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_image_play"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/p10"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.425"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/icon1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_quiz"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/p10"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnlay"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.563" />

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/btnlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.541" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/validate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Check"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnlay"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

so my expectation output should be like this:

[image]

Comment: have you debug your for loop and checked whether it is working fine?

Comment: @karan my code works but it display only one button in my grid layout

Comment: You are removing view before adding next.

Comment: comment tour remove view line

Comment: Ill try to remove it ill update you

Comment: @karan i got the display now but the button are not spreading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `GridLayout`, use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` and a span size of 2. There are number of benefits using `RecyclerView` over `GridLayout` if you want to populate your view according to an `ArrayList`.

Comment: is there any example for this recycler view using arraylist? i cannot find any solution or any layout for my code

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/13792/android-gridlayoutmanager-example

Comment: go through it bro you will get it .

Comment: thank you for this information ill update you after the output.. thank you